# How to apply EnterKey within InputField on Wolfram Cloud page?

Tags: cloud

I created InputField on the Wolfram Cloud page.
What I want is that the line changes when I press Enter Key,
If you press Shift+EnterKey, the calculation will be executed.
The following code works well with Mathematica.

```
DynamicModule[ {input = "1+1 
5! 
Plot[x,{x,-1,1}]"}, 
Manipulate[  Column[{
EventHandler[
 InputField[Dynamic@input, String, Alignment -> {Left, Center},
  ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 10}},
  FrameMargins -> 10, ImageSize -> {300, {75, Automatic}}], { 
  "ReturnKeyDown" :> If[! CurrentValue["ShiftKey"], Paste["\n"]],
  {"MenuCommand", "HandleShiftReturn"} :> {},
  {"MenuCommand", "EvaluateCells"} :> {}}, 
 PassEventsDown -> False], "",
 Dynamic@
 Column[ToExpression@StringSplit[input, {"\n"}], Spacings -> 2, 
  Dividers -> Center, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Lighter@Gray, Thin]]}], 
AppearanceElements -> None, ContentSize -> {320, 320}]]
```

[image]

However, if you publish the above code to Wolfram Cloud,
The Enter Key is not working.

[enter link description here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/mathought/Published/test.nb)  (Wolfram Cloud Test Page)

[image]

How to apply EnterKey within InputField on Wolfram Cloud page?